# Posting large array to ASP.NET server

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp32

I have an array defined as

```
struct TDataR 
{
int x;
int y;
int z;
float pos;
}

TDataR data[17000];
```

I wish to send this array to an ASP.NET controller, yet

```
HTTPClient *http;
http->post( );
```

seems like does not provide such a direct option to post it as a body of a post.

- How to post to ASP.NET controller such a large array ?

Comment: Pls show  us what you have tried so far and what it the problem? If it is too big for one time it can be separated into the pieces

Comment: Someone changed the tag incorectly to ASP-MVC, while this is pure Arduino question.